# Prove that $\cup_{i \in I} A_i$ is an open set.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. We call A an open set if $\forall a \in A$, $\exists r>0$ such that $(a-r,a+r) \subset A$. Let $A_i$ be a family of open sets indexed by I. Prove that $\cup_{i \in I} A_i$ is an open set.

I think I have lack of understanding of open set, and I don't know how to interpret the definition of union of set with open set to prove this. I do not have solid proof, but here's what I have:

Let $a \in \cup_{i \in I} A_i$. There exists $r > 0$ such that $(a-r, a+r) \subseteq \cup_{i \in I} A_i$. Also, there exists $k \in I$ such that $a \in A_k$.

I don't know how to proceed next. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start from what you know, which is that each of the $A_i$ are open.

So, let $a\in\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$.  Then there exists $i'\in I$ such that $a\in A_{i'}$.  But we know that $A_{i'}$ is open... what does that tell you?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I guess if $A_{i^{\prime}}$ is open, then every element in $A_{i^{\prime}}$ also open? it might be just notation, but where does the $i^{\prime}$ come from?

Comment: The definition of the union -- if an element is in the union, then it must be in (at least) one of the constituent components of the union.

Now the key is that $A_{i'}$ is open.  You defined what it means for a set to be open up top...

Comment: I'm not sure I still have the right idea. I'm totally lost on this, but "Since $A_{i{\prime}}$ is a family of open sets indexed by $I$ and open, for all $a \in A_{i{\prime}}$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $(a - r, a + r) \subset A$." does this make sense?

Comment: I figured it out. thank you for the help. I did start with "Let $a \in \cup_{i \in I} A_i$, the there exists $k \in I$ such that $a \in A_k$. Since $A_k$ is an open set and $a \in A_k$, there exists $n > 0$ such that $(a-r, a+r) \subseteq A_k$."